# How to copy values from a non const vector to a const vector in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have the following class where I have a private member `vectortest` which I would like to use as a computation variable for operations within the class member functions. Then, I would copy the computed vector to another vector `cvectorin`, which is a public member but a constant so that the contents cannot be modified, yet is accessible. I tried the following (both assignment as well as std::copy):

```
class constVecTest
{
  private:
    vector<int> vectortest;
  public:
    constVecTest(vector<int> vin);
    const vector<int> cvectorin;
    vector<int> vectorin;
    void vecOp1();
    void vecOp2(vector<int> vin);
};

constVecTest::constVecTest(vector<int> vin)
{
  vecOp1();
  vecOp2(vin);
}

void constVecTest::vecOp1()
{
  vectortest = {1, 0, 1, 0, 1};
  // cvectorin = vectortest;
  copy(vectortest.begin(), vectortest.end(), back_inserter(cvectorin));
}

void constVecTest::vecOp2(vector<int> vin)
{
  vectortest = vin;
  vectorin = vectortest;
}


int main()
{
  vector<int> input {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, cvo, cvc;

  constVecTest cvt(input);
  cvo = cvt.vectorin;
  cvc = cvt.cvectorin;
  
  return 0;
}
```

But I get the error:

```
error: passing ‘const std::vector<int>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

I'm new to vectors and couldn't find any good example on such a scenario. How do I achieve what I intend to? If the above approach is not the right one, I would be glad to learn a new alternative.

Comment: You can't copy things to a `const vector`, because, well, it's `const`, i.e. immutable.

Comment: A `const` variable cannot be changed during its lifetime.  That is the purpose of `const`.  It is asking the compiler to make sure change is not allowed.

Comment: @churill Is there an an alternate way that I can make a public member of vector<int> type accessible but unmodifiable?

Comment: @skrowten_hermit make a getter that returns a `const&` ref to it.

Comment: @underscore_d Sorry couldn't quite get it. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @skrowten_hermit I mean you could have the member itself be non-`const`, and `private`, then provide `public` access via a member function that returns a `const&` reference to the member, thus making public access be `const` only. But if you can instead have the member be `const` at declaration as indicated by aschepler, you don't really need to. It's then a matter of preference whether you use a getter function or just access directly.

Comment: @underscore_d Understood now. Yeah, both would do the job. But I think via function is preferable for me for readability and flexibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, a better approach would be to change your API to look something like this:

```
class constVecTest
{
  private:
    vector<int> vectortest;
    vector<int> cvectorin;
  public:
    constVecTest(vector<int> vin);
    const vector<int> &get_cvectorin() const { return cvectorin; }
    vector<int> vectorin;
    void vecOp1();
    void vecOp2(vector<int> vin);
};
```

Now the public access is const, so external users can't modify the vector, but your private members are free to modify it.

Comment: This looks nice and clean and exactly what I was hoping for. So, now I can keep only these get functions and move other computations to private scope.

Answer (score 1):

The `const` member can't be modified after it is first created, even from the body of the constructor.

But by rearranging things, you can change *how* that member is first created:

```
class constVecTest
{
  private:
    vector<int> vectortest;
    static vector<int> vecOp1();
  public:
    constVecTest(vector<int> vin);
    const vector<int> cvectorin;
    vector<int> vectorin;
    void vecOp2(vector<int> vin);
};

constVecTest::constVecTest(vector<int> vin)
    : vectortest(),         // Create this one empty.
      cvectorin(vecOp1()),  // Create cvectorin from the result of vecOp1().
      vectorin()            // Another empty.
{
    vecOp2(vin);
}

vector<int> constVecTest::vecOp1()
{
    vector<int> result = {1, 0, 1, 0, 1};
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is great. But the above example I provided is just a prototype. My actual application is more complex with many more variables (vectors, structs etc) and functions and I'm afraid the initializer list length would be too long. But a nice solution for smaller classes and informative too. Will definitely use this wherever possible.